# PHP foreach as new url

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am using CodeIgniter PHP framework. Trying to make a all kind of products rent page. What I have done yet:
using codeigniter shopping cart and made that users could add some products. 
Now products are shown like:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypFoF.png)

Without a link or something. 
I would like, that every this product could have unique link, and on Button press, pop up new window. I am using foreach. It is possible somehow to do that?

PHP code:

```
<?php
                        foreach($product as $row)
            {

                echo '  
                <div class="col-md-4" style="padding:16px; background-color:#f1f1f1; border:1px solid #ccc;
                margin-bottom:16px; height:100%" align="center">
                <img src="'.base_url().'/myassets/images/'.$row->product_image.'" class="img-thumbnail" height="2000" width="2000" />
                    <h4>'.$row->product_name.'</h4>
                    <h3 class="text-danger">'.$row->product_price.' €(dienai)</h3>
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity" placeholder="Dienų skaičius" id="'.$row->product_id.'" />
                    <b>Patalpino: </b><i>'.$row->owner.'</i></b></br/>
                    <button type="button" name="add_cart" class="btn btn-success add_cart" data-productname="'.$row->product_name.'"
                    data-price="'.$row->product_price.'" data-productid="'.$row->product_id.'" />Rezervuoti</button>
                </div>
                ';
            }
            ?>
```

Could I some how edit this foreach loop to create a url for each product?
Each product has unique product ID, maybe link could go like `localhost/Shopping_cart/112` or etc.?
**MySQL**:

```
product_id
category_id
product_name
product_price
```

Next step will be a Search engine if it will be possible to manage it.

Comment: First of all how you want output? 1. On pop up window 2. on new window. Clear It. If you want in Pop up window ( Use bootstrap modal) else use anchor tag with target="_blank"

Answer (score 0):

You should have to open bootstrap modal.When ever add to cart button click then call a javascript function and pass a product id.And ajax through from that pass id show data of product in the in modal.

here is a sample code.

```
  function get_product_detail(id)
  {
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo site_url();?>Controller/function/"+id,
      }).success(function(data) {

      $("#product_data").html(data);
      $("#modal").modal("show");

   });
  }
```

And the controller side display product data with html.